# Adding a CRM Analytics Dashboard to a Salesforce page so users without license can see it?

Tags: dashboard, crm-analytics

I want to add a CRM Analytics Dashboard to a Home tab in Salesforce so users without CRM Analytics license can have view it, but was wondering if this is possible, or is it necessary to buy a separate license for each sure so is there a view-only permission?

I was trying by adding the "Analytics View Only Embedded App" Permission Set License to the user and then added the CRM Dashboard component to a home page in Lightning app builder. It did display, and I see the loading screen but it ends up saying “Dashboard not found…”

Could someone please help me to find if I'm in the right track or if this is not possible at all?

**If I assign myself a CRM Analytics Plus license the component displays correctly

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The App containing this dashboard and datasets etc has not been shared with the user. Verify that the user has [access to the App](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.bi_app_sharing.htm&type=5). The user should be able to view the dashboard once given access.